# how do I call the asset_pipeline for only 1 file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to understand the asset_pipeline.

I basically have all my website-wide code in style.css.scss (which is @imported in application.css.scss)

I also have a few miscellaneous controllers that have code that I split off into a separate file only to be loaded on that page. For example, in my profiles_controller I have profiles.css.scss and profiles.js

in the documentation it says i can conditionally include those by typing:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
```

and a similar one for javascript_include_tag

The problem is when i view source on any of my pages that dont have a controller stylesheet it is a 404 file not found. I dont want to have 10 blank files for each controller and 10 blank javascript files (those controllers have hardly any extra css or code, so i put it in the main scss file) ... am i doing this wrong?

Note:I have removed include tree from the JS and css files, as i dont want any file in that folder being included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application layout file, add `yield` statements like this to pull in the stylesheets you include as one-offs in different views:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag    "application"
= yield :stylesheets 
= javascript_include_tag "application"
= yield :javascripts
```

Then in each view file where you want to include stylesheets:

```
= content_for :stylesheets do
  = stylesheet_link_tag "controller_name"

= content_for :javascripts do
  = javascript_include_tag "controller_name"
```

This will include those files in only the views you need them in.